# Sub menu not working in Chronicle Theme WordPress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have menu issues. My application will be intranet solution. so cant show a demo. Please imagine .

Menu structure 
Home > About

About page working .

Home > About > Vision Mission .

About page not working .

Answer (score 0):

Open "chronicle-menu.js" from core theme directory.

Now copy the code from this [LINK](http://pastebin.com/HUX79XRt) and replace with "chronicle-menu.js"

file code of your core theme directory.

save the changes.

Thanks.